# Return an element of inner object Spring Repository, Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using SpringRepository to query mongo db. I have a `students` collection with documents like the following.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52f2139ee4b0384b7402c520"),
    "subjects": [
         {
             "subjectId" : "s001",
             "subjectName" : "maths"
         },
         {
             "subjectId" : "s002",
             "subjectName" : "science"
         },             
    ]
}
```

I'm going to query this collection using Spring Repository for a subject. I can get a student list with a particular subject like this

```
@Query("{ 'subjects.subjectName' : ?0 }")
List<Student> findBySubjectName(String subjectName);
```

But if I want subject only, how to return the a Subject object matching the subject name?

Answer (score 0):

This should work: (untested code...)

```
@Query(value="{ 'subjects.subjectName' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'subjects.$' : 1 }")
List<Student> findBySubjectName(String subjectName);
```

The basic syntax of projections with `@Query` can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.0.RC1/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html), the projection syntax from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097176/mongodb-subelement-querying).

Note that you will still obtain a `Student` object with `null` mapped to all fields that have not been fetched. If you don't want that, you will have to implement the query yourself (which is not hard) and return the required field of the fetched document in your method.

Comment: Can't I fetch Subject object directly?

Comment: for all I know not via annotations