# Get a value of item in the array

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a structure and I want to find a value of token which is a sub-item of `access_tokens` for a comparing value of tokens. How can I find a token?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa28846de35244ec439a563"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5a9d53e52d989d2accda2ee5"),
    "refresh_token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyZWZyZXNoX3Rva2VuIiwianRpIjoiNWE1NDZmOGQtNjBjMy00YmYzLTk0OGQtYjJiM2E5MDU5MWMwIiwib2JqZWN0aWQiOiI1YTlkNTNlNTJkOTg5ZDJhY2NkYTJlZTUiLCJleHAiOjE1MjA2MDQ3MjMsImlzcyI6IlByb25ldCBBUyIsImF1ZCI6IkF1dGhBcGkifQ.sxfUJgFnfMKKtSOLzksfPB-FqQN4ydaKi9YAVZqobK4",
    "expTime" : "9.03.2018 14:12:03",
    "access_tokens" : [{
        "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJqdGkiOiIxMzM1Nzg0My0xNzRhLTQwOWYtOTgyMS0yY2ZhN2U1NmE5NDYiLCJvYmplY3RpZCI6IjVhOWQ1M2U1MmQ5ODlkMmFjY2RhMmVlNSIsImV4cCI6MTUyMDYwNDcyMywiaXNzIjoiUHJvbmV0IEFTIiwiYXVkIjoiQXV0aEFwaSJ9.KgYWj8w89W4DsyX5pkg7OPuCyT2DFUSAktkMmlb1kOk",
        "exp_date" : "9.03.2018 14:12:03"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb subelement querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097176/mongodb-subelement-querying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have class for my access token which is called SubToken and there is a structure for a collection which stored in mongodb and it is called TokenCollection. I reached subtoken (access token) which is sub item of a refresh token it is called Token.

```
 SubToken res = TokenCollection.Find(new BsonDocument { { "access_tokens.token", access_token } }).FirstAsync().Result.access_tokens.Find(x => x.token == access_token);
```